# Does encrypting the session cookie protect against spoofing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, encryption, cookies

In Rails 4, the session id can be stored in an `EncryptedCookieStore` and thus be unreadable by the client ([see the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage) and the [Hartl Rails Tutorial, Chapter 8](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#cha-basic_login)). If the user can't read the cookie, she can't tamper with it either. However, if the app is accessed over (insecure) `http`, and there is no additional protection such as tying the session id to the user's IP address, couldn't anyone listening in intercept the cookie, without being able to read or tamper with it, and use it to spoof the user's session? In other words, does encrypting the session id provide any protection against an outside attacker, or just against a malicious user?